# Can I search questions from the mobile versions of Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: support

I posted a question about Mint on Server Fault. I asked if its stellar UI was accompanied by any system administration headaches due to possible incompatibilities with plain old Ubuntu.

I can't find it listed under my own questions, and I couldn't find a general question search in the mobile UI.

Is searching supported on the iPhone UI? And has my post been deleted for whatever reason?

Comment: My guess (although only a SF moderator could confirm) is that the post was deleted- it sounds like a Not Constructive, or possibly Off-Topic, question. (Also, why ask about both this and the mobile UI search in the same question?)

Comment: Yes, searching is supported. The search box is in the drop-down menu when you push the down arrow in the top-right corner. But as David says above, it was likely deleted if it's not in your questions list anymore.